# Looping through rows and columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to loop through the rows and columns in a dataframe. My dataframe looks like this:

My code looks like this:

```
for index,j in usd_margin_data.iterrows():
    print(index,j)
```

But I actually want is loop rows and column in the data.

Something like this:

```
for row in usd_margin_data.iterrows():
     for column in list(usd_margin_data):
```

What is the best way to loop through rows and columns, where I need the index for each row and column?

The expected output

```
10 CME 1728005
10 HKEX 0
10 Nissan 1397464.22
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For loop is possible use:

```
for r,j in usd_margin_data.iterrows():
    for c, val in j.items():
        print(r,c,val)
```

If want 3 columns DataFrame with remove missing values:

```
df = usd_margin_data.stack().rename_axis(('row','col')).reset_index(name='val')
```

And then for loop is possible use [`itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html):

```
for x in df.itertuples():
    print (x.row, x.col, x.val)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
val = pd.melt(df, id_vars='acct')
val[val.value.notnull()]
```